# EF can't return the items with condition but sql can why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a query like this :

```
   int a= pgc.Fronts.Where(i => i.ItemCode == itemcode && i.PC == pc).Count()
```

PGC is my dbcontext .The itemcode is '10414' and the pc value is `null` the result is `0`.

So i changed the query to sql command :

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT  [Id]
      ,[No]
      ,[ItemCode]
      ,[QtyRequest]
      ,[PC]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Line]
      ,[joint]
      ,[QTYIssue]
      ,[Recivedby]
  FROM [pgc].[dbo].[Fronts] where ItemCode='10414' and pc is null
```

it returns 3 records as you can see here :

[image]

So why it happens ?

```
 public partial class Front
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string No { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> QtyRequest { get; set; }
        public string PC { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Line { get; set; }
        public string joint { get; set; }
        public double QTYIssue { get; set; }
        public string Recivedby { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly (at least for Linq2Sql) if you want to compare with null values you should use [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int a = pgc.Fronts.Where(i => 
               i.ItemCode == itemcode && Object.Equals(i.PC, pc)).Count();
```

This "bug" seems to have been fixed in later versions of Entity framework. For now you can use:

```
int a = pgc.Fronts.Where(i => 
      i.ItemCode == itemcode && (i.PC == pc || (pc == null && i.PC == null)).Count();
```

Comment: Thank you it works ,what about the PC values ,does it apply to query?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?